# Identity of covariant derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

I was reading about Einstein-Hilbert action, and in some point [in this page](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acci%C3%B3n_de_Einstein-Hilbert) they use this identity

$$\sqrt{-g}A^{a}_{;a}=(\sqrt{-g}A^{a})_{,a}$$

I Know that $\nabla_{\sigma}g_{\mu\nu}=0$. And $g$ is the determinant of the metric. However I can't see how to get the equation   $\sqrt{-g}A^{a}_{;a}=(\sqrt{-g}A^{a})_{,a}$  , can you help me?

Comment: $g \neq g^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu \nu}$.  The components $g^{\mu \nu}$ are the matrix inverse of the components $g_{\mu \nu}$, so $g^{\mu \nu} g_{\mu \nu} = \delta^{\mu}_\mu = 4$ in 3+1 dimensions.  $g$ is the matrix determinant of the components $g_{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: Oh you are rigth. I'm sorry.
I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $J:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}V$ where $V^\mu$ is a vector field. Your question can now be now written as.

> **Claim** 
>   The covariant divergence of a vector field $J$ can be expressed in terms of the flat spacetime divergence $V^\mu{}_{,\mu}$, i.e. 
>   $$J^\mu{}_{;\mu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}V^\mu{}_{,\mu}.$$

*Proof.*
Show the following things in this order

1. $J^\mu{}_{;\mu} = J^\mu{}_{,\mu} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\nu}J^\nu$
2. $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\lambda}\partial_\nu g_{\lambda\mu}=\frac{1}{2}tr(g^{-1}\partial_\nu g)$
3. $\partial_\mu \sqrt{-g} = tr(g^{-1}\partial_\mu g)$
4. $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\nu \sqrt{-g}$
5. $J^\mu{}_{;\mu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}V^\mu{}_{,\mu}$. To this end it might be worth expanding the following equation 
   $$\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt{-g}J^\mu\right).$$

I hope this helps. Some of the steps need some mathematical tricks, but other than that, this should be quite straight forward. Feel free to ask further questions.

*Note:* You can use this to show that the Maxwell equations in curved spacetime have essentially the same form as in flat spacetime.

Comment: I think that the equation number 4 has a typo. It should be $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_{\nu}\sqrt{-g}$

Comment: Also the first equation has a typo. The first term shold be $J^{\mu}_{,\mu}$. However I don't see how to get the equation five

Comment: Yes I get the equation number 4

Comment: Thank you for your help